# Building dictionary dynamically from json config

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an input list from users and a standard config. Only user_input can change. based on the user_input , would need to select only required data in a dictionary. ie Most of the config would remain as it is, just fruits are filtered based on user_input.

```
user_input = ['Apple','Grapes','Watermelon']
superset_config = """
[   
    {
     "input":"source_1",
     "operation":"add",
     "fruits": {
               "Apple":"Red",
               "Grapes": ["Red","Yellow"],
               "Orange": "Yellow"
               },
        "output":"target_1"
    },
    {
     "input":"source_2",
     "fruits": { "Watermelon":"green"},
     "output":"target_2"
    }    
]
"""
```

Desired results: just remove 'Orange' from fruits, as Orange is not part of user input.rest everything is same.

```
[   
    {
     "input":"source_1",
     "operation":"add",
     "fruits": {
               "Apple":"Red",
               "Grapes": ["Red","Yellow"]
               },
        "output":"target_1"
    },
    {
     "input":"source_2",
     "fruits": { "Watermelon":"green"},
     "output":"target_2"
    }    
]
```

Transform:

```
import json
superset_definitions = json.loads(superset_config)
superset_definitions    

filtered_common_defintion = []
for each_input in user_input:
    for each_node in superset_definitions:
        if  each_input in each_node['fruits'].keys():
            temp_dictionary = {}
            temp_dictionary[each_input] = each_node['fruits'][each_input]
            filtered_common_defintion.append(temp_dictionary)
filtered_common_defintion
```

The above code performs filter on fruits, but I am not sure how to capture remaining elements of the config. Can someone please guide?

Comment: create a copy of `each_input`, then filter the fruits in the new input, then append that to your filtered_common_definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.load` to convert JSON string to a python dictionary, then iterate the list of the dictionary, and create a temporary dictionary to hold the values, if the key is `fruits` take only the key in `user_input`, and corresponding values from the dictionary, otherwise, just store it in temporary dictionary, finally, append each such dictionary to a resulting list:

```py
result = []
for d in json.loads(superset_config):
    temp = {}
    for k in d:
        if k=='fruits':
            fruits = {key:value for key,value in d[k].items() if key in user_input}
            temp[k] = fruits
        else:
            temp[k] = d[k ]
    result.append(temp)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[{'input': 'source_1',
  'operation': 'add', 
  'fruits': {'Apple': 'Red', 
             'Grapes': ['Red', 'Yellow']
             },
  'output': 'target_1'},
 {'input': 'source_2',
  'fruits': {'Watermelon': 'green'
             },
  'output': 'target_2'}]
```

Comment: Don't use update to assign a value to a key, i.e. `mydict.update({key:value})` should just be `mydict[key] = value`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yeah that can be done. But I'm generally used to `update` since it allows to assign multiple key/values via dictionary unpacking. Anyways, I have updated the solution respecting your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's ***Dictionary Comprehension***

```py
for each in superset_definitions:
    each['fruits'] = {k: v for k, v in each['fruits'].items() if k in user_input}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach for the same:

```
import json
import copy
user_input = ['Apple','Grapes','Watermelon']
superset_config = """
[   
    {
     "input":"source_1",
     "operation":"add",
     "fruits": {
               "Apple":"Red",
               "Grapes": ["Red","Yellow"],
               "Orange": "Yellow"
               },
        "output":"target_1"
    },
    {
     "input":"source_2",
     "fruits": { "Watermelon":"green"},
     "output":"target_2"
    }    
]
"""

config = json.loads(superset_config)

for item in config:
    for fruit_name, fruit_value in list(item["fruits"].items()):
        if fruit_name not in user_input:
            del item["fruits"][fruit_name]
            
print (config)
```

Output:

```
[{'input': 'source_1', 'operation': 'add', 'fruits': {'Apple': 'Red', 'Grapes': ['Red', 'Yellow']}, 'output': 'target_1'}, {'input': 'source_2', 'fruits': {'Watermelon': 'green'}, 'output': 'target_2'}]
```